# Defining n-dimensional rotation matrices as a function of some free parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I am looking to solve an optimization problem which has a particular rotation matrix (i.e. orthonormal basis) as its solution. More specifically.
I'm looking to solve the problem numerically with gradient descent, so effectively what I need to make it work is a function that, for some set of parameters, is able to generate any rotation matrix, but also generates *only* rotation matrices.

My first idea was to use Givens rotations, so that my function is defined over a set of $\binom{n}{2}$ angles that rotate around each (n-2)-dimensional main plane. The overall function would be:

$f(\vec{\theta}) := \prod_{i,a>b} G_{a,b}(\theta_i)$

i.e. the product of all the main rotations, given arbitrary angles $\vec{\theta}$. However, generating this matrix symbolically for each optimization is a bit expensive, and I was wondering if there is a simpler formulation of a (differentiable) function that achieves the same: given some parameters / angles, generate an orthonormal matrix.

Comment: One such parameterization is given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1365121/153694, also the discussion and links here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377001/is-there-a-canonical-way-to-parameterize-elements-of-operatornameson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Cayley Transform achieves this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform

I can generate a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ (with $\binom{k}{2}$ free parameters $\theta$), then generate a orthonormal basis $Q$ using:

$Q=(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$.

I can then optimize my function of A with respect to $\theta$. This is pretty similar to my previous approach, but a bit similar to formulate.